# How to copy or move a doc file to "my drive"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am quite new in app script.. I found the way to move or copy a doc file to a dedicated folder on a drive (with the Id), but I did not find a way to put it on the home folder "My Drive".
The "create" function does create the file in "My Drive" but I did not find a way to do it using "makecopy" or "moveto"

Any help would be highly appreciated :)
Peter

I have tried to find if there is a "root" folder corresponding to "my drive". But I could not find it.

Comment: Try [DriveApp.getRootFolder()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getrootfolder)

Answer (score 0):

```
function copyAFileToRootFolder() {
  const t = DriveApp.getFileById("fileid");//file to copy
  t.makeCopy(DriveApp.getRootFolder());
}
```

- [DriveApp makeCopy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname,-destination)
- [DriveApp.getFileById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  It saved me a lot of time